# Natural Probability distribution on finite group involving irreducible representation and characters

Tags: group-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $\lambda$ be an irrep (irreducible representation) of some finite group $G$ (say over the complex number $\mathbb{C}$). Then consider the function $P_\lambda: G \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
P_\lambda(g) = \frac{1}{|G|} \chi_\lambda^*(g) \chi_\lambda(g) = \frac{1}{|G|} |\chi_\lambda(g)|^2,
$$
where $\chi_\lambda(g) = Tr(\lambda(g))$ is the character corresponding to $\lambda$.

Note that $P_\lambda$ can be interpreted as a probability distribution on the set $G$ because $P_\lambda \geq 0$ and
$$
\sum_{g \in G} P_\lambda(g) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_\lambda^*(g) \chi_\lambda(g) = \langle \lambda, \lambda \rangle = 1,
$$
which follows from the inner product of characters and the irreducibility of $\lambda$.

Does this probability distribution have a name? Or has this probability distribution ever been studied? In what contexts has this distribution come up?

Of course if $\lambda$ is $1$-dim then this is just the uniform distribution on $G$ but more generally this seems to be an interesting and natural distribution.